# Getting error when trying to echo string to a file

Tags: shell

I have got the below content from a JSON API. I am trying to create a Markdown file from this content using the below script.

````sh
body="**Weekly Report 28-10-2020 for ravsam-web**\r\n\r\nJekyll website of RavSam\r\n\r\n**Updations**\r\n\r\n- Added json feed blog with 110 changes\r\n- Just some minor layout changes with 43 changes\r\n- Replaced blog images path with 6 changes\r\n- Commit added support for json feed with 155 changes\r\n\r\n\r\n```\r\nsend-email ravgeetdhillon@gmail.com\r\n```\r\n\r\n<sub>Created by [Github Actions](http://github.com/ravsamhq/client-reports)</sub>\r\n"

echo $body > ravgeet.md
````

Whenever I execute the above script, I get this error `markdown.sh: line 3: rnsend-email: command not found`. Any reason why?

Comment: Use single quotes ( `'` ) around the string.

Comment: More importantly, use double quotes around the variable.

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes, single quotes worked. But this is what I got in the Markdown file ```
**Weekly Report 28-10-2020 for ravsam-web**\r\n\r\nJekyll website of RavSam\r\n\r\n**Updations**\r\n\r\n- Added json feed blog with 110 changes\r\n- Just some minor layout changes with 43 changes\r\n- Replaced blog images path with 6 changes\r\n- Commit added support for json feed with 155 changes\r\n\r\n\r\n```\r\nsend-email ravgeetdhillon@gmail.com\r\n```\r\n\r\n<sub>Created by [Github Actions](http://github.com/ravsamhq/client-reports)</sub>
```
How do I get the clean markdown with carriage returns?

Comment: Note that neither the shell nor `echo` understand constructs like `\n`. `printf` does, when used correctly. But if the source is JSON then a proper JSON parser should solve all that for you.

Comment: @RavgeetDhillon JSON and `printf` _happen to_ share some escape syntax. If the (unparsed!) JSON string contains a `\u…` in the future then it won’t work.

Comment: The take-away is ... this is a good example of why you don't want to manipulate .json files with shell.... Shell and shell tools are generally limited to processing ASCII (and while `\`\`\`` qualifies) and single-quotes prevent the *command substitution*, any other unicode will generally fail.